# Enable selectable on kendo grid programmatically

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, jquery-ui-selectable

I have this grid in my application.

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Something>
          ()
          .Name("Something")
          .Selectable(builder => builder.Type(GridSelectionType.Row).Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple).Enabled(false) )
          .ClientRowTemplate(Html.Partial("Partials/Something").ToHtmlString())
          .TableHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "table table-stripped" })
          .Scrollable(scrollable => scrollable.Height(100).Enabled(true))
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(h => h.Something).Title("Something").Width(120);
              columns.Bound(h => h.Something).Title("Something").Width(120);
              columns.Bound(h => h.Something).Title("Something");
          }))
```

This grid is populated when I select another grid.
Once it is populated, I should be able to select multiple rows.
I looked evrywhere for a value that I could change, but no luck so far.
How or where can I change this

```
 .Selectable(builder => builder.Type(GridSelectionType.Row).Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple).Enabled(false) )
```

to

```
 .Selectable(builder => builder.Type(GridSelectionType.Row).Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple).Enabled(true) )
```

programmatically?

Tks in advance.
Rui Martins

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following code:

```
.Selectable(selectable => selectable
    .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
```

You can view a demo [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/selection).